# Optimal Airplane trajectory

Tags: variational-calculus, optimization

The last time I took a plane the following problem crossed my mind.

Setting: take the Earth and neglect its rotation around the Sun. It then only rotates on itself with angular velocity $\Omega$.
Assume an airplane is flying with constant velocity $v$ in this absolute reference frame, at a constant altitude, i.e. we consider a constant radial coordinate $R$. The angle variables are $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$ and $0\leq\phi\leq 2\pi$ . The non rotating relative frame would be $\theta'=\theta$,  $\phi'=\phi+\Omega T$.

Given a starting point $(\theta_0,0)$ and an endpoint  $(\theta_f,\phi_f)$, what is the path $(\theta,\phi)$ which minimize the flight time $T$ ?

I think we have:

$$
T = \dfrac{1}{v}\int ds = \dfrac{R}{v}\int\limits_0^{\phi_f + \Omega T}\underbrace{\sqrt{(\dfrac{d\theta}{d\phi})^2+\sin^2(\theta)}}_{\mathcal L}d\phi
$$

which at first variation is

$$
\delta T = \dfrac{R}{v} \left\{
\int\limits_0^{\phi_f + \Omega T}
\left(\dfrac{\partial \mathcal L}{ \partial \theta} -
\dfrac{d}{d\phi}
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal L}{ \partial \dfrac{d\theta}{d\phi}}  
\right)\delta\theta d\phi 
+ 
\left[
\delta\theta
\dfrac{\partial \mathcal L}{ \partial \dfrac{d\theta}{d\phi}}
\right]^{\phi_f + \Omega T}_0
+
\delta T \Omega
\left[
 \mathcal L
\right]_{\phi_f + \Omega T}
\right\}.
$$

Given the implicit character of the last equation, I think we should use some perturbative approach. Intuitively, the small expansion parameter is $R\Omega/v$. However I am unsure as to how to proceed.

Indeed setting $\delta T = 0$ leave only two terms, but 
unlike classical equation of motions, I think we can't choose $\delta \theta$ such that the second term (boundary term) vanishes. This is because changing $\theta\rightarrow\theta+\delta\theta$ changes the boundary condition as well, because $T=T(\theta)$. This is further supported that by doing so we are back to standard non rotating case, i.e. shortest path on a sphere.

Does anyone have any idea to get some (even approximate) solution to this problem ? Is there any more elegant way to proceed ?

Comment: my guess would be by using parallel transport(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_transport), you do need knowledge of the covariant derivative for that, but if you assume the earth is a spere you should get there I think ?

Comment: Thank you Nick for your comment.
I know of Parallel transport, but fail to see the use here. There are only two interesting frames: the absolute one (the one I used in the post above), and the relative one. The problem in solving in the rotating frame is that the condition of constant absolute velocity is cumbersome, leading to solve for $\theta(t)$ after having used some relation of the form $\dot\phi'=\dot\phi'(v,\theta,\dot\theta)$.

Comment: my best guess would be to solve the geodesic equation, which would yield a big set of coupled differential equations, but due to your symmetries that you assume I think you can simplify the whole bunch by using Killing vectors.

Answer (score 1):

The great circle route works because the atmosphere is not rotating relative to the earth. i.e. The atmosphere at altitudes where most aircraft can fly rotates at the same speed as the earth. Are you assuming otherwise? If not, forget my comment

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted. To me it also seems that the questioner assumes that the atmosphere is not rotating with earth, which is wrong.

Comment: In fact this is the correct answer under the assumption of the question.  Of course in practice jetliners either go with or avoid air currents (v.g. Jetstream) and so the actual flight times and flight path are not quite the geodesics.  Airliners are also subject to ATC and other organizational requirements .  See for instance https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/North_Atlantic_Tracks.